# Remove all Google Contacts and keep all WhatsApp Contacts?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-contacts

I want to clean up deep and remove all contacts in my address book, but keep the contacts, that are linked to WhatsApp. So how to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid You can't. whatsApp uses contacts in your address book.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove/delete contacts then whatsapp linked contacts also will be deleted. So how can you Keep WhatsApp contacts only?.
But you can view only whatsapp linked contacts
goto

1. Contacts App
2. Click on Options
3. Click on Contacts to View
4. Select WhatsApp from the list
5. Now you can view only WhatsApp contacts